# how to retrieve WP_Query without ordering by date

Tags: wordpress

I want to use

```
$ps = "9126,8955,8554,8620,8825,8912,8937,8813,9054,9022";
$recent = new WP_Query( array('post__in' => explode(',', $ps)) );
```

to retrieve posts by ID, I do and the result ordered by publish date but I want to retrieve in same of IDs in this example in this order:

```
9126,8955,8554,8620,8825,8912,8937,8813,9054,9022
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in the future in wordpress 3.5 you can use: `'orderby'=>'post__in'`

Answer (score 2):

Personally, if the order of posts as well as your ID numbers are going to be that strict, I would probably avoid using WP_Query:

```
<?php
$ids = array(9126,8955,8554,8620,8825,8912,8937,8813,9054,9022);
foreach($ids as $id)
{
    $post = get_post($id);
    setup_postdata($post);
    ?>
    <!-- YOUR HTML HERE -->
    <?php
}
?>
```

Otherwise, since Posts do not have any kind of Menu Order option like Pages do, you will probably have to set a Custom Field and give it a value (with lower numbers taking priority over higher numbers). Then you can do something like this:

```
<?php
$ids = array(9126,8955,8554,8620,8825,8912,8937,8813,9054,9022);
$recent = new WP_Query(array('post__in' => $ids, 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'meta_key' => 'postOrder', 'order' => 'ASC'));
?>
```

This second option is untested and I can't guarantee it will work right off the bat, but it should get you started. Good luck.

Comment: I tested ur answer and no result

Comment: That's why I said "This second option is untested and I can't guarantee it will work right off the bat, but it should get you started". Also, "it doesn't work" doesn't tell me anything. I'm basing my answer off the code you give me. If you want a more specific answer, you will need to provide more code.